# Finding n numbers common over N lists

Tags: python, primes, intersection

I am trying to solve this problem (from [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=60)).

> The primes 3, 7, 109, and 673, are quite remarkable. By taking any two
>   primes and concatenating them in any order the result will always be
>   prime. For example, taking 7 and 109, both 7109 and 1097 are prime.
>   The sum of these four primes, 792, represents the lowest sum for a set
>   of four primes with this property.
>
> Find the lowest sum for a set of five primes for which any two primes
>   concatenate to produce another prime.

For replicating the scenario, considering the fact that for 4 prime numbers of the interest (3,7, 109, 673)

1. 673 is the highest number with 673109 as the upper limit

I used seive of Erathosenes to generate prime number till 700000 and stored it in a list.

And derived prime number till 700 and stored it in another list .

Now,

```
l = [3,5,7,11 ...] -- till 700
primes = [3,5,.....] - till 700000
```

Now, I compared each number in the list with other prime numbers by adding prefix and suffix.

Take , 3 and compare it with 5 . 35 and 53 are not prime. then compare with 7 . 37 and 73 are prime. Hence insert 7 into list.

End of loop for 3, insert into a dictionary with 3 as key and list of numbers matching the property for 3 in list as Value . I also added the key value to the list.

Hence, I end up with a dictionary like this

```
key : 3 , Value : 3, 7, 11, ..., 109 , ... 673 
key : 7 , Value : 3, 7, 11, .., 109, 673
key : 11, Value : ......
..
..
.. 
key 673 , Value : 3,7, .. 109, 673
```

Now, i have 123 lists, in which only 4 lists are having 3,7,109 and 673.

**How do I retrieve the common numbers over those lists?**

I don't know how to compare 4 lists for matching elements.

But, if there is some way where we can derive 4 numbers which are common in 4 lists, then I've solved the Project Euler problem.  I can apply same logic for 5 numbers by increasing the upper limit.

My current code :

```
   def eratosthenes2(n):
    multiples = set()
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        if i not in multiples:
            yield i
            multiples.update(range(i*i, n+1, i))

primes = list(eratosthenes2(700000))

def isReversedPrime(m,n):
    if( int( str(m) + str(n) ) in primes and int( str(n) + str(m) ) in primes ):
        return True
    else:
        return False

f1 = open('logs.txt', 'w+')


toCheck = list(eratosthenes2(700))
#toCheck = [ i for i in range(2,700)]
d = {}

print "Total Elements " , len(toCheck)
for i in range(len(toCheck)):
    print "Checking for ", toCheck[i], " iteration ", i
    l = []
    for j in range(len(toCheck)):
        if isReversedPrime(toCheck[i], toCheck[j]) == True :
            l.append(toCheck[j])
    #print toCheck[i] , " has " , len(l), " elements "
    if len(l) > 0:
        d[toCheck[i]] = l
    #print "\n"
```

Comment: are the numbers sorted?

Comment: Yes, they are sorted .. But the below answer works out only if 3, 7, 109 and 673 are alone repeated. I have other numbers repeating too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set.intersection` to find common elements.

```
>>> list1 = set([1,2,3,4])
>>> list2 = set([2,3,4,5])
>>> list3 = set([3,4,5,6])
>>> lists = [list1, list2, list3]
>>> set.intersection(*lists)
set([3,4])
```

Comment: I understand this . But , i have other numbers also repeating in the list .. 

l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
l2 = [1,3,5,6,7]
l3 = [1,2,3,5,7]
l4 = [1,4,3,6]
l5 = [1,3,5,7,9]

I want the list which has 1,3,5, 7.. 

i have 3, 7, 109, 673 common in only 4 lists over 123.